# gRPC соединение ssl не может быть установлено

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-5

Проблема следующая: запускаю приложение клиента локально (на одной машине с сервером; Windows 10) - ошибки нет, но на другом компьютере (также Windows 10) в одной локальной сети клиент выдает следующую ошибку:

```
The SSL connection could not be established <...> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Я понимаю, что проблема с сертификатом, но не понимаю, как её решить. Находил варианты решения с помощью игнорирования невалидного сертификата или отключения шифрования, но мне нужно шифрование, желательно, грамотно организованное. Прошу подсказать с решением. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: можно попытаться экспортировать сертификат из сервер и добавить его как "доверенный" у клиента

Comment: можно создать свой СА и свои сертификаты и использовать их на клиенте и сервере, а если это реально приложение, то получить/купить сертификаты у настоящего СА

Comment: @ExplodingKitten я экспортировал сертификат из сервера и, вроде как, сделал доверенным на клиенте, но все равно не понимаю ничего. Сделал так на сервере: `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. Потом также на сервере ввел: `dotnet dev-certs https -ep "C:\devcert.pfx" --trust`. Далее на клиенте уже ввел: `dotnet dev-certs https --clean -i "C:\devcert.pfx" -p np`. Но ошибка так и осталась.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten добавил сертификат с машины-сервера на машину-клиент (в том числе сделал доверенным) через `certmgr.msc`, но клиент все-равно выдает ошибку.